# How do you get the kernel config to compile a new kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, ovh

I have patched several kernels in the past with GRsec but have always been able to find the config under /boot. This is a OVH box but I can't find any *config* located anywhere.

Is there a way to get the config or how do I compile a kernel blind without a prebuilt config?

```
Linux astro.srv.com 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #9 SMP Thu Oct 20 14:53:52 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is a Debian 8 machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the `.config` file from [here](ftp://ftp.ovh.net/made-in-ovh/bzImage/3.14.32/)

```
wget ftp://ftp.ovh.net/made-in-ovh/bzImage/3.14.32/config-3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can do the following:

```
cp /proc/config.gz ~
gunzip config.gz
cp config ~/linux*/.config
```

Comment: Or more simply `zcat /proc/config.gz >.config`. The file `/proc/config.gz` doesn't exist everywhere, it requires a patch to the mainstream kernel.